# Local extrema of function in circle

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am supposed to find the local extrema of function: $f\left ( x,y \right )=x^{2}+2x+y^{2}-2y+3$ with origin in the coordinate axis and radius $2\sqrt{2}$.

Equation for the circle is: $y=\sqrt{8-x^{2}}$ and I put it in my original equation, then I calculated the first derivation:

$\frac{\partial f\left ( x,y \right )}{\partial x}=2+\frac{2x}{\sqrt{8-x^{2}}}$ and I found stationary points: $x=2,x=-2$. But I do not know, what to do next, or how to find points for y.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The equation of the full circle is $x^2+y^2=8$.  You'll find $y=2$ for $x=-2$ and $y=-2$ for $x=2$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Can you elaborate answer, as I can see the process of solving it?

Comment: Following your approach, for $y=\sqrt{8-x^2}$ the only zero of the derivative is $x=-2$, for $y=-\sqrt{8-x^2}$ you'll find $x=2$.

Comment: I found x=2 nad x=-2 too, but how you got y?

Comment: $2+\frac{2\cdot2}{\sqrt{8-2^2}}\neq0$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe nad now when I have them, do I have to calculate the second partial derivation? Because I did, but I do not know how to made Hessian metrix

Answer (score 1):

With Lagrange multipliers:

$H(x,y, \lambda):=f(x,y) + \lambda (x^2+y^2-8)$

Solve the system

$H_x=0$

$H_y=0$

$H_{\lambda}=0$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: I do not think so, can you elaborate it?

Comment: This are my points for Hessian matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Using $x^2+y^2=8$

and $(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2=2(?)$

$$\implies(x-y)^2\le2(x^2+y^2)=?$$

$$(x-y)\le4$$

$$f(x)=8+3+2(x-y)\le11+2(?)$$

Alternatively $x=2\sqrt2\cos t,y=2\sqrt2\sin t$

and $\cos t-\sin t=\sqrt2\cos (t+\pi/4)\le?$

Comment: Your last proposal seems the easiest.

Comment: Cannot I just solve it with second derivation and Hessian matrix? I do not understand your solution

Comment: @Daniel, DEFINITELY. But I believe this method is much easier. Please let me know the point of confusion